# Hazelcast 5.2.2 Hang in the Imap get function

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We have recently upgraded our Hazelcast platform version from 3.12.13 to 5.2.2. After the upgrade we are facing: com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException GetOperation invocation failed to complete due to operation-heartbeat-timeout.
We use a two node Hazelcast cluster. In our Java application code we use several IMaps. The exception is always happening while performing a get operation on one particular IMap. This happens around the same time a node is also performing remove operations operations on this IMap. It is possible that the key for both the remove and get operations are the same. The application ran fine with 3.12.13. Is there any difference between the versions that may cause this operation timeout?

We have tried an IMAP and a multimap. The interesting thing to keep in mind is that we have some itemRemoved callbacks which also do Imap gets.

Comment: If code for `EntryRemovedListener` makes a Hazelcast call in the same thread, there is the chance of deadlock in either 3.* or 5.*. If you're doing this you might just be lucky with 3* and unlucky with 5.* -- but launching a separate thread (and don't wait for it) should make both safe. If it's not that, a code sample might be helpful.

Comment: The issue is resolved. Thank you. Some callbacks were throwing an exception. We had to set config.setProperty("hazelcast.io.write.through","false"); to get around this.